# Android - "Navigation destination that matches request NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app:/XXX } cannot be found" in fragment testing

Tags: fragment, android-architecture-navigation, dagger-hilt, modularization, instrumented-test

I'm working on a multi-module single activity application. Each feature module has its own navigation graph. I'm trying to navigate to a feature module from the another one using deep link as recommended in the official doc.
([here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/integrations/multi-module#across))

When I run the app, there is no problem. Navigation with deeplink working well. But, when I try to test my fragment via testNavHostController gives error below:

```
Navigation destination that matches request NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app:/com.x.y/home } cannot be found in the navigation graph NavGraph(x_navigation)
```

x_navigation means my feature module's nav graph. I'm launching fragment by using Hilt-testing library for fragment isolation test.

```
   launchFragmentInHiltContainer<F>(
            fragmentArgs = fragmentArgs,
            themeResId = themeResId,
        ) {
            testNavHostController.setGraph(graphResId)
            testNavHostController.setCurrentDestination(destinationId)
            Navigation.setViewNavController(requireView(), testNavHostController)
        }
```

AGP Version: 8.0 
navigation-fragment-ktx Version: 2.5.3

I think that deep links are not loaded in fragment isolation test because the fragment is initialized in a container(HiltTestActivity) and it does not contain all navigation graphs like MainActivity.  I tried to move all navigations to a single module like [this](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/issues/663).

However, It gave the runtime error as I expected (I think the reason was my AGP version).

If you link me about a sample code or share your experiences about this issue, I'll be greateful.

Have a nice day.
Tugce.